# Unable to use/mount/initialize/format Ipod in Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, ipod

I was given an Ipod touch 2g by a friend.  Used it for awhile on its own, but wanted to link it to my computer.  Tried Gtkpod & Rythymbox for mounting/syncing Ipod with Ubuntu, but there always comes a pt. where something fails or simply doesn't exist as the instructions say, and then I'm lost, as I am essentially computer illiterate (a friend set up Ubuntu for me, but he doesn't know mp3s) So I 'wiped' it by clicking 'reset all settings'.  Now it's useless.  Touch screen shows a usb cord aiming at ITunes logo.   So, what to do?  Currently, when my computer asks if I want to Initialize Ipod, and I click OK, I get this error message:

DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Mountpoint Already registered

My computer is using Lucid Lynx

ps - unclear on distinction among sync, mount & initialize...

Comment: Ipods need to connect to iTunes at least once to get registered with an iTunes account. You'll need to do it on a Windows or Mac OS X machine (or virtual machine) before anything running in Ubuntu will work as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need a Windows or Mac OS environment to initialize your iPod.  once you have that, i *believe* you can use it via iTunes in Ubuntu, but you have to init it via Windows or Mac first.

Comment: OK - hadn't seen TLoT's answer before I edited.  Will attempt to initialize via Windows.  But then I HAVE to use iTunes in Ubuntu?  Any further clarification appreciated.

Comment: That's not what I said.  I merely said you need a Windows or Mac environment to init the device.  I didn't say you have to, i said you can.  not that you have to.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  Can I then use it with something else - like Rhythmbox or gtkpod in Ubuntu, without using iTunes after the initialization in Windows or Mac?

Comment: I tend not to use my iPhone music sync with anything other than iTunes, mainly because its the ***iPhone*** and i don't want to risk it dying, so I can't answer that question.

Comment: All I want is to be able to save/play mp3s (podcasts, mostly) from my laptop to/on the Ipod.  Doesn't seem a lot to ask.  But remains out of reach.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever configure your iPod initially?

Comment: Yes, finally initialized it on a windows machine, then tried the ideviceactive suggestion below.  No go.

Comment: Try connecting your iPod to Rythmbox.  Note this doesn't work 100% well with the iPod Touch, and I've seen this break iPhones.  And if you're on Lucid, you may not have a new enough version of the software that is used to access/read those devices.

Comment: When Rythymbox opens, it says "Unable to mount bob's iPod   DBus error   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs:   Mountpoint Already Registered"

Comment: Bob is the friend on who's computer I just initialized the iPod.  But I got the "Mountpoint Already Registered" message prior to that initialization...

Comment: That I can't help you with, I've never run into those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ideviceactive` from the libimobiledevice suite to activate your device from Ubuntu.

Since you are using 10.04, download it from here: https://github.com/posixninja/ideviceactivate/ ([Direct Link](https://github.com/posixninja/ideviceactivate/archive/master.zip))

And follow the instructions:

```
Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
cd Desktop/ideviceactivate-master
make
sudo make install
ideviceactivate
```

Comment: Thanks.  What exactly do I type after cd ideviceactivate?  Path to extraction is /home/dc/Desktop/ideviceactivate-master.  Have tried a couple of versions (with/without #) but it returns "no such file or directory"

Comment: I've changed the instructions above. Post the output in the question if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks.  Pasted in below my attempt which failed:  Oops.  Can't paste in -  too long.  Not sure what you need to help.  I don't think I got it downloaded correctly - what does 'fetch your dependencies' mean?

Comment: Tried again-got this:
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dc/Desktop/ideviceactivate-master/src'
gcc -o ideviceactivate ideviceactivate.c activate.c cache.c util.c -g -pthread -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -limobiledevice -lplist -lusbmuxd -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lgnutls -ltasn1 -lxml2 -lglib-2.0 -lcurl
ideviceactivate.c:27:39: error: libimobiledevice/lockdown.h: No such file or directory
ideviceactivate.c:28:47: error: libimobiledevice

...plus much more error stuff, too long to post here.Help!